# GAWK strftime doesn't recognize a passed variable

Tags: gawk, strftime

I am not able to pass `$daysSeconds` in `GAWK` My expression doesn't evaluate correctly

```
#___________
days=20
daysSeconds=$(expr $days \* 86400)
DAY=`gawk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%d", systime() - $daysSeconds )}'`
echo $DAY
#____
```

Comment: @swapna : The result I am expecting 18, but it returns 07 for todays date 07-11-2013

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do.
`%d The day of the month as a decimal number (01–31).`

You should not mix parentheses `$()` and back tics.  Use parentheses.
You should not use variable directly in awk.
It seems to be a problem with you begin block do like this:

```
DAY=$(echo "$daysSeconds" | awk '{print strftime("%d",systime()-$1)}')
```

Gives `18` for `$DAY`